# Kivy DropDown not affected by max_height

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I've noticed some strange behaviour of the `DropDown` widget in Kivy `v1.9.2-dev0`.
The [documentation](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.dropdown.html#kivy.uix.dropdown.DropDown.max_height) states:

> `max_height`
>   Indicate the maximum height that the dropdown can take. If `None`, it will take the maximum height available until the top or bottom of the screen is reached.

However, that does not seem to be the case. Here is an example from that docs page (slightly modified):

```
from kivy.uix.dropdown import DropDown
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.base import runTouchApp

max_hgt = 1     # This should affect the dropdown, but it doesn't

dropdown = DropDown(max_height = max_hgt)
for index in range(20):
    btn = Button(text='Value %d' % index, size_hint_y=None, height=44)
    btn.bind(on_release=lambda btn: dropdown.select(btn.text))

    dropdown.add_widget(btn)

mainbutton = Button(text='Hello', size_hint=(None, None))
mainbutton.bind(on_release=dropdown.open)
dropdown.bind(on_select=lambda instance, x: setattr(mainbutton, 'text', x))

runTouchApp(mainbutton)
```

So I thought that the `DropDown` will limit to `max_hgt`, but changing it does not change the size of the content - it still stops at the top of the screen.
Is it a Kivy problem or am I not understanding the `max_height` property correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seemed to indeed be a bug, i just sent a pull request  to fix it (https://github.com/kivy/kivy/pull/4550), thanks for reporting, and sorry for the long delay!

edit: fix was merged

Comment: Hmm.. this still doesn't seem to be working for me.  I used pip to upgrade to the latest version of kivy 1.9.1 and ran the above code; changing around max_hgt had no effect.  Is the fix only in the development version?  Unrelated question: do you know why there is a delay when clicking a button in dropdown?  There's a maybe half-second delay before a button highlights when holding it down which does not occur with a button outside of a spinner or dropdown.

EDIT: Current 1.9.1 is from January so of course fix isn't in there.. I'll try the dev version if I can get it running.